# Как скопировать один файл в разные каталоги одновременно?

Tags: c#

Думал написать вот так:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            File.Copy(Path,NewName1, true);
                        });
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            File.Copy(Path,NewName2, true);
                        });
```

Но бьет исключение, что файл занят другим процессом: *An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "D:\output\log4.txt", так как этот файл используется другим процессом.* Есть ли возможность или какие-то варианты одновременно скопировать файл по разным путям? Или есть какие-то варианты ускорить сей процесс? Спасибо.

Comment: Если нет каких то специфических требований, то последовательно в один поток будет определенно быстрее

Comment: Если речь идет о записи на один и тот же логический носитель — то да, обрабатывать файлы последовательно будет быстрее. Однако если запись ведется на разные логические носители — картина полностью меняется.

Comment: У вас один и тот же `NewName`? Покажите реальный код.

Comment: @PavelDmitrenko а если несложно, можете вкратце объяснить?

Comment: Да, файл один и тот же. Логические носители могут быть как разные, так и один.

Comment: @user3195373 если на писать на один физ.носитель, то одновременная  запись все только замедлит: в ОБЩЕМ  случае, если речь идет о HDD, то головки блока дисков будут часто перепозиционироваться в попытках записать фрагменты на разные физические области диска.

Comment: VladD,  не говорил,что пишу в один и тот же файл ! Копирую один и тот же файл в разные места.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Реализация через `FileStream` *(в зависимости от типичного для задачи объема файла имеет смысл поэкспериментировать с размером буфера)*:

```
public void ParallelCopy(string src, params string[] dsts)
 {
    Parallel.ForEach(dsts, new ParallelOptions(),
        dstOne =>
           {
              using (FileStream source = new FileStream(src, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))

               using (FileStream destination = new FileStream(dstOne, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            var buffer = new byte[4096];
                            int read;

                            while ((read = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                destination.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                            }
                        }

                    });
            }
```

Использование:

```
ParallelCopy(@"x:\source.file", @"c:\destination1.file", @"d:\destination2.file");
```

Comment: А размерность буфера исходя из чего определяли? Размер майла может быть от 1 до 100 МБ

Comment: Ее можно определить только исходя из реальных условий, так что в данном случае считайте, что она условно-случайная.

Comment: Вот неплохое [обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033771/file-i-o-with-streams-best-memory-buffer-size) оптимального размера буфера. Канва такова, что 4096 байтов считается средне-оптимальным значением.

Comment: @PavelDmitrenko 4096 байт - дефолтный размер логического кластера в NTFS, потому и получается оптимальным, что это количество данных читается или пишется за одну операцию чтения или записи (обеспечивается буфером диска). Если размер кластера логического диска будет другим, то и оптимальный буфер изменится.

Comment: @PavelDmitrenko В комментариях указано, что конкретно для копирования используется более крупный буфер.

Comment: @rdorn FileStream.Read не обязательно лезет на диск, с большой вероятностью ось прочитает гораздо больший кусок заранее, если заметит последовательный доступ, поэтому размер кластера иррелевантен.

Comment: @Squidward не совсем. прочитанный кусок будет как минимум кратным размеру кластера. ФС не умеет отдавать кластеры кусками, так что, даже если файл(часть файла) занимает меньше одного кластера - читаться будет весь. А дальше зависит от оптимизации системы, если при повторном обращении она не полезет читать то, что уже прочитано, то все хорошо, а если полезет  - то мы получим лишние чтения при не кратном буфере. Эта тема старая, сомневаюсь что там что-то новое появилось, ну кроме размера кэшей.

Comment: @rdorn Из моего опыта все прочитанные файлы оказываются в оперативной памяти целиком, если память позволяет. / Если вы идеально выравниваете кластеры и читаете непоследовательно, может, размер и имеет значение. А тут копирование от и до с единственным чтением.

Comment: @Squidward ну так в вопросе речь про одновременное копирование, так что в любом случае будет непоследовательный доступ на запись, а буфер в обоих случаях используется один и тот-же. Про чтение ни кто и не спорит, понятно что большинство файлов читается целиком если позволяют ресурсы.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так еще проще:

```
public void ParallelCopy(string src, params string[] dsts)
{
  var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(src);
  Parallel.ForEach(dsts, d => File.WriteAllBytes(bytes, d));
}
```

Comment: +1, но это если файл помещается в память